# Rabbitvsc in Nautilus both git and svn

Tags: svn, git, ubuntu-12.10, nautilus

I'm new to Linux, I have ubuntu 12.10.
I have installed Rabbitvsc 0.15.2.

We have both .git and .svn in our project.
We use git locally, and svn with our client.
This worked great on Windows, we used Tortoise SVN for svn, and used git from command prompt.

On Ubuntu 12.10 my problem is:
in Nautilus if I have both .git and .svn in the project folder, the context menu shows only RabbitVcs GIT options, and I can't select SVN.

I use git mostly from the terminal, but I want to use the gui for svn.